# Looking for 80s-90s film with reptilian aliens featuring a man trying to rescue a teenaged girl

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I'm 30 years old now. I remember when I was very young, likely age < 10, I watched this horror movie with this ending. I did not watch this movie from theater but on TV, so it could be purchased from the US after a few years' of release. The movie is color. So it has to be something from maybe 1980 - 1994 ... I guess?

Solid clues:

- The main characters center around a male protagonist very close to a teenage girl. Not sure if she's her daughter.
- There are aliens. They are anthropomorphic reptilian with lizard-like scale skin.
- The near-ending scene was the girl got captured and was about to be operated in the same way. The male protagonist found out and can only watch hopeless through the air vent above the operating room. He reached out his right hand only to be cut off at wrist by a sneering alien.
- The ending scene is the male protagonist woke up and lost his right hand at wrist level, where the girl sit watching him and speak a final time at half half angle. The girl turns to him and reveals to be half lizard and half human now, and left with the lizards and said she is sorry and had to go. The male protagonist cries and is the end of the movie.

Fuzzy clues:

- There was a scene where the male protagonist was placed on an operating table, and then the aliens start to cover a piece of skin/cloth over him and simmer some dust... and then the skin starts to bind him and shape him into an alien. Of course, he escaped in the end. However, that is the scene he found out those aliens were formerly human.  (VERY FUZZY. COULD BE ANOTHER MOVIE. I have always been fascinated about the operation scenes of converting human to alien, so this may be from another movie since there could be two movies converting humans to aliens)
- It's in some spaceship or space... I think. Since there are aliens.

Sorry this is so vague but that is all I can remember. Thank you!!! I've tried to go through many space movies in Wikipedia at the time but could not find out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [The Outer Limits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112111/) episode [Quality of Mercy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_Mercy_(The_Outer_Limits)), (1995).  (At the end, though, she's not sorry.)

> After Skokes is thrown into the cell, he sees his fellow prisoner and,
>   suspicious, questions her about her name, background, and unit. Her
>   name is Bree Tristan, and she is a cadet. He spots a strange growth on
>   her arm, and she tells him that the alien jailers have been
>   experimenting by **grafting samples of their own skin onto her**,
>   seemingly in an effort to make her into one of them.
>
> ...
>
> Skokes believes he can cut through another set of bars and escape the
>   roof tunnel. He climbs up, and while crawling along the tunnel, hears
>   Bree being taken again. Looking down into a cell, he sees her being
>   experimented on and attempts to stab the guard through the bars. The
>   guard grabs his arm and **cuts off his hand**. He wakes later back in his
>   cell, with Bree looking on, now **extensively transformed**. She has given
>   up hope and wants to die.

The full episode is available on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORwYSBvHoEs).